# SOLR - how to manage number the number of request sent to solr server

Tags: java, solr

I'm using solr 4, and when i'm trying to do a "Search-As-You-Type" interface using wildcards. the problem is when the number of request sent to solr server is over 70 requests/minute the server is shutting down and my CPU hits 100% and response time for indexing increases a lot.. And i get Out Of Memory Error.
Is there a solution to limit number of request sent to slor server.
Thanks in avdance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to optimize SOLR performance. Also look for throttle control options in documentation.

Comment: Thank you for responding,I know that i have to optimize SOLR, can you explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

From what you say your main issue might not been SOLR config but you sending two much query to SOLR, you have to work on your "Search-As-You-Type" interface to reduce the number of calls with some rules, like:

not sending a query each time a letter is typed: when a letter is typed, start a timer and if after x ms (500ms?) the content in your field is still the same then do the query (wait for the user to have finished typing before querying)

Comment: Thank you for responsing, Yes i did that on client side, the OnChange event attached to my textField is detected after 1000ms so  the request is sent after 1000ms. But that not resolving the problem.